# Landline listening

Tags: microcontroller, msp430, telephone

I still have a good old landline at home. But I miss the easiness of cell phones where you can just see a list of missed calls. I'm a MSP430 Launchpad hobbyist and I'm alway looking for some little projects. I wonder if there is a way to tap my own landline and listen for calls. This should be passive listening, so no need to answer the call. I'm living in Belgium, is the signal on our lines encrypted?

Comment: Do you have caller ID? You could try to decode that using an MSP430 otherwise you won't have any audio unless you answer the phone. There are a few legal / safety issues related to connecting stuff to phone lines though.

Comment: Our telecom provider asks a monthly fee for Caller ID. We didn't picked that option because the prices the service providers in Belgium are asking are (too) high. I allready thought that there would be legal issues. At home, they won't be that happy at all when I would destroy their landline. Maybe I should catalog this idea in the "don't try it" box. ;-)

Comment: Take a look at this [closed] question that contains some info on Caller ID if you're interested in that: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32277/how-to-build-a-telephone-answering-machine-with-caller-id/32287#32287

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the U.S., an incoming call would start with ringing, which is an AC signal of around 60V, then proceed to a modulated Caller ID signal after the first ring. It could be similar in Belgium.

So it would take some dedicated circuitry to handle and detect the 60V ringing and then decode the Caller ID. It is messy in the sense that you have to handle the 60V and the plain old telephone scheme of things. If you do a search on Caller ID circuits, you would find lots of information, most of them old.

Recently, I put together something to monitor incoming call with my computer. What I did was to buy an USB telephone data modem (I got mine from Ebay for $10). The modem would handle the interface to the telephone line. The Modem's USB connection would appear as a serial port to the computer software. The software would use the serial port communication to initialize the modem (using the "AT" command set) and then to receive the caller ID information.

To have a modem interfaced to a MSP430, you probably need to use the RS232 type serial interface (not the emulated serial interface through USB). Nowadays, the only serial port modem available might have to be an old used one.

Answer (score 2):

Well ring voltage is a pretty high ac voltage so you could run one conductor through a current transformer and measure with the msp430.   Take a look for msp430 smart meter reference designs to get an idea of what it would take to do it.

Or look up the silabs proslic, they have a global reference design for interfacing to pots.  You could just use the ring detect feature.

Or buy an answering machine :).